# What is returned from a javascript match statement?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code:

```
    if ($selectInput.data('propagate-title') === 'yes') {
        var m = this.id.match(/^modal_TempRowKey_(\d+)$/);
        if (m) {
            $("#modal_Title_" + m[1]).val(title);
        }
    }
```

Can someone explain what is returned and put into m. Can I just change the code to the following and have it work the same?

```
    if ($selectInput.data('propagate-title') === 'yes') {
        var m = this.id.match(/^modal_TempRowKey_(\d+)$/)[1];
        if (m) {
            $("#modal_Title_" + m).val(title);
        }
    }
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is an important difference between the two code fragments.  You can not make the change you wish because if there is no match, `null` will be returned from the `match` operation, and the result of evaluating

```
null[1]
```

would throw an error, something like

```
TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of null
```

The return value of `match` is an array if the regex matches, or `null` if there is no match.  Element 0 of the returned array is the whole match, element 1 would be the match within the parenthesis-pair starting with the first `(`.  In the first code fragment, the value `m[1]` is the digit sequence following `"modal_TempRowKey_"`.

EDIT: See the link provided by Kyle in the comment to the original question for all the details.

Answer (score 1):

[Here is match method explanation.](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_match.asp)
**An array containing the matches, one item for each match, or null if no match is found**

id is matched with your regular expression, it returns array or else null, and returned array is assigned to m.
So m[1](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_match.asp) is used in first code.

id is matched with your regular expression, it returns array and array[1](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_match.asp) is assigned to m.
So m is used in second code.

If your id is not match case, in second code you would get null or undefined exception, but first doesn't.